# Currying is just "optional parameters"?

Tags: lambda, functional-programming, currying

I read a guy's statement on the web saying "currying is just a fancy way of having optional parameters". By gut, I feel that the statement is shallow and wrong but I can't really put my finger on it, probably because I don't have enough knowledge on lambda calculus.

When I try to explain the difference my explanation spans paragraphs, mostly coming down to "Currying is having all variations of a function's declaration with less number of parameters as types. But you cannot have all combinations of a function with optional parameters as valid types and use them in other declarations, at least not automatically".

Is my approach right at the beginning, and more importantly is there a simpler, plainer way to explain it?

Comment: Optional parameters produce a different *result.* Currying returns a different *function.*

Comment: Values for optional parameters must be known at compile-time ?

Comment: @Skeptic: Depends on the language.

Comment: @Skeptic: IIRC, VB6's optional parameters allow any value.

Comment: Just in case, see ["Practical use of curried functions?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4888480/298282). There's a useful link there.

Comment: @Craig, that is also a good summary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has nothing to do with anything being *optional*.

But instead of defining a function which takes two parameters, you can define one which takes only one parameter, and returns a function which takes the other parameter.

The end result is the same (the caller ends up providing two parameters), but with currying, you only provide one at a time.

Comment: A nice advantage is the fact that like this all functions take exactly one argument and produce exactly one result.

Comment: @Martinho, and how is that an advantage?

Comment: @ssg: It's nice from a theoretical perspective, since it makes it easier to reason about programs; and thanks to automatic currying, the user never needs to notice, unless it's to their advantage to notice.

Comment: @ssg: a more practical advantage is that it gives you an easy way to specialize functions. Take a function like `map`, for example: a general function which applies *some* operation to every element in a list. With currying, you can supply this "some operation" first, resulting in a specialized function which applies that specific function to every element in a list. Currying makes it very convenient to write extremely generalized and reusable functions, and then specialize them as required for the specific use case.

Comment: In OOP, object constructors are kind of a poor mans way to achieve the same: in the constructor you supply some "initial" data, which affects how the member methods on the object will work. It's generally very useful to be able to provide data for a function call in stages, providing general data first, which can be reused across several calls, and then providing the per-call data separately.